# Is it possible to ignore Ember CLI's http-mocks proxy server?

Tags: ember-cli

I've created some `ember g http-mock`s, and they live in my ember app under `/server`.

I'd also like to be able to run my ember cli app, proxying all api requests to localhost:3000.

It seems if `/server` exists, ember will use it, regardless of the `-proxy` flag. I found some discussion about a `--no-http-mocks` flag near [the end of this issue](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1921), but I don't think there's a formal proposal yet.

Is there any hackish intermediate way to get ember cli to ignore `/server`, other than by deleting the entire `/server` directory?

Comment: I guess you could just `mv app/server app/server-disabled` and then create/delete a symbolic link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably set up ember-cli to enable/disable http-mock based on an environments.js variable as described here:
http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-disable-http-mock-server-within-environment-config-file/6660

Then to manually flip http-mock on and off as you like, pass in a process environment variable when you run your ember serve at command line. Seems like the way to do that is in this SO post:
[How to pass API keys in environment variables to Ember CLI using process.env?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403334/how-to-pass-api-keys-in-environment-variables-to-ember-cli-using-process-env)