# How to access environment variables in .profile for a controller?

Tags: ember.js

I have a problem accessing the environment variables in my EmberJs app.

I want to use the environment variable set in the .profile file of the server.

My .profile in the server

```
export SERVER_NODE=testNode
```

I already tried this solution :

- process.env like node.js in my config/environment.js but it doesn't
  work, i cannot access it in my app ([Stack Post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403334/how-to-pass-api-keys-in-environment-variables-to-ember-cli-using-process-env))

So if you have any idea about how I can do this, I take it.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `ember-cli-dotenv` Ember addon: https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-cli-dotenv

This will let you access variables from a `.env` file in `config/environment.js`. You can then access these variables from a component or service by importing `config/environment.js`.

Example:

**.env**

```
CLIENT_KEY=THEKEY
CLIENT_SECRET=SECRETSECRET
```

**config/environment.js**

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    API: {
      clientKey: process.env.CLIENT_KEY,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
    }
  }
};
```

**app/services/example.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ENV from '../config/environment';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  clientKey: ENV.API.clientKey, // 'THEKEY'
  clientSecret: ENV.API.clientSecret // 'SECRETSECRET'
});
```