# How to add a custom environment for Ember js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using Ember.js `2.5.0` and it seems at the moment Ember is limited to the three environments `development`, `test` and `production`. How can I add some other env like as for example `staging`?

I have a staging server so we can test our app and I want to use different configurations there (than the development one). Any workaround to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and I've resolved it editing two files `environment.js` and `ember-cli-build.js`

In `environment.js` I've added another IF to set values for the new environment:

```
if(environment === "stage") {
  ENV.APP.xxxx = 'stage value'
}
```

In `ember-cli-build.js` I've customized how the `fingerprint` is enabled or not. You can do the same for other settings.

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var fingerprintEnabled = false;
  var env = process.env.EMBER_ENV || 'development';
  switch (env) {
    case 'development':
      fingerprintEnabled = false;
      break;
    case 'test':
      fingerprintEnabled = false;
      break;
    case 'production':
    case 'stage':
      fingerprintEnabled = true;
      break;
  }
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    fingerprint: {
      enabled: fingerprintEnabled,
      exclude: [...]
    }
    // Add options here
  });
```

When building the app I pass the proper `environment` flag:

```
ember build --environment=stage
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Could you explain what the `fingerprint` is for? Do you inherit all production settings for staging somehow?

Comment: I mean, I get that fingerprint is only one setting. But is there a way to inherit all unchanged settings from production?

Comment: No, I don't inherit production settings, I had only the need to override the fingerprint setting.

Answer (score 2):

As it states in [ember-cli documentation](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#Environments), ember-cli is limited to three environments at the moment.

The best workaround at this stage is to use something like [ember-cli-dotenv](https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-cli-dotenv). Have a look specifically at [this part of the readme](https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-cli-dotenv#multiple-environments).

Pasted here for easier reference:

```
// ember-cli-build.js

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    dotEnv: {
      clientAllowedKeys: ['DROPBOX_KEY'],
      path: './path/to/.env'
    }
  });

  return app.toTree();
};
```

Where DROPBOX_KEY can now be anything according do your .env.

Related SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403334/how-to-pass-api-keys-in-environment-variables-to-ember-cli-using-process-env).

Comment: Thanks for your willing to help @TameBadger. Is that a common practice tho? I mean Ember already provides `environment.js` to handle this, would it be good to use `dotenv` in this case? no simpler solution in this case?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/660 and https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3176 for related discussions and also https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/1520